# Is Tresina Lobi a Chev or a Chevin?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

The Jedi [**Tresina Lobi**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tresina_Lobi) became a semi-major character during the later years of the Yuuzhan Vong story arc. During the first meeting of the new Jedi Council, she was called a [Chev](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chev), yet described as having the standard [Chevin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chevin/Legends) appearance:

> To Saba's right was Sien Sovv, the Supreme Commander, and between Sovv and Luke bulked *the wrinkled gray frame of the Chev Jedi Knight Tresina Lobi, whose long snout was partly unrolled on the surface of the table*.

Later during the [Dark Nest trilogy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dark_Nest_Trilogy), she was described as appearing like a human with pale skin, which is the standard appearance for a Chev:

> A golden-haired Chev woman, *Lobi resembled a pale-skinned human with obsidian eyes, a heavy brow, and a sloping forehead*.

Her Wookieepedia article describes her as Chev, but obviously in her earlier appearances she was meant to be a Chevin like [Ephant Mon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ephant_Mon) in Episode VI. Both species hail from the same system, with the Chev acting as a slave race for the Chevin.

**Which description of Tresina Lobi is accurate, and why the change?**

The preferred answer would include a reference to the discrepancy from one of the authors or anyone else involved with the books, but if needed I'll accept anything that proves a reason for the change.

Comment: The wookieepedia article you've linked says ***"Lobi was mistakenly identified and described as a Chevin in The New Jedi Order: Destiny's Way."***. Is that not sufficient answer for you?

Comment: @Valorum - whoops, didn't see that. I can either close the question, or if you want, make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll do a bit of research to see if I can track down the source of the Wookieepedia assertion